# Как обеспечить минимальный радиус кубическим Безье?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, svg, canvas, html5-canvas

**Строится кривая, состоящая из множества кубических Безье, следующих друг за другом. Пробую обеспечить отсутствие крутых поворотов со сверхмалым радиусом, изломов.**

Для этого вычисляю угол, образующийся между условным последним отрезком (по двум последним точкам) и предполагаемым следующим отрезком (до точки со случайными координатами). Если угол меньше `MIN_ANGLE`, то вызываю рекурсивно функцию `getPoint()`, которая генерирует случайную точку, проверяет минимальный угол и записывает точки в `lastTwoPoints` для последующей проверки.

Дополнительно добавил проверку на минимальное и максимальное расстояние для предполагаемого отрезка: `MIN_DISTANCE` и `MAX_DISTANCE`. Так я пытаюсь исключить изломы на минимальных отрезках и перекосы при слишком больших.

Результат удовлетворительный, но не идеальный. Изломы все-таки не исключены, да к тому же при многократных неудачных попытках перебора точек иногда получаю ошибку `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

**Как обеспечить отсутствие изломов кривых Безье и схожих с ними участками со сверхмалыми радиусами?**

Здесь строится SVG-path, который точно так же может быть отрисован и на Canvas, поэтому в метках стоит `canvas` и `html5-canvas`.

```js
let lastTwoPoints = [];

const W = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
const H = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

const MIN_ANGLE = 60;
const MIN_DISTANCE = (Math.min(W,H))/20;
const MAX_DISTANCE = (Math.min(W,H))/4;

let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
let path = document.querySelector('path');

//svg.style.width = W;
//svg.style.height = H;

svg.setAttribute('viewbox', `0 0 ${W} ${H}`);

createPath();

function getPoint(){
    let x = getRandomNumber(W*0.6) + W*0.2;
    let y = getRandomNumber(H*0.6) + H*0.2;
        
    let point = [x,y];

    if(lastTwoPoints.length < 2){
        lastTwoPoints.push(point);
    } else {
        if(getAngle(...lastTwoPoints, point) < MIN_ANGLE
            || getDistance(lastTwoPoints[1],point) < MIN_DISTANCE
            || getDistance(lastTwoPoints[1],point) > MAX_DISTANCE){
            point = getPoint();
        } else {
            lastTwoPoints.shift();
            lastTwoPoints.push(point);
        }
    }
    return point;
}

function pointString(){
    let point = getPoint();
    return `${point[0]} ${point[1]} `;
}

function getDistance(pointA, pointB){
    return Math.sqrt((pointA[0] - pointB[0])**2 + (pointA[1] - pointB[1])**2);
}

function getAngle(pointA, pointB, pointC){ // angle in pointB
    let a = getDistance(pointA, pointB);
    let b = getDistance(pointB, pointC);
    let c = getDistance(pointC, pointA);
    return Math.acos((a*a + b*b - c*c)/(2*a*b))*(180/Math.PI);
}

function createPath() {

    let path_string = `M ${pointString()} C ${pointString()} ${pointString()} ${pointString()}`;

    for( let i = 0; i < 100; i++  ) {
      path_string += `S ${pointString()} ${pointString()} `
    }
    
    path.setAttribute('d', path_string);
}


function getRandomNumber(max) { return Math.floor( Math.random() * max ); }
```

```html
<svg fill="none" stroke="black" viewbox="0 0 600 200">
    <path d=""/>
</svg>
```

Переработка вопроса и попытки ответа на [enSo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68512066/creating-random-svg-curves-in-javascript-while-avoiding-sharp-turns).

Comment: Что-то я не пойму откуда берутся точки. Чистый рандом? Хочется просто рандомную кривую?

Comment: Да все точки рандомные, первые две записываются в lastTwoPoints как есть, а каждая следующая проверяется относительно двух записанных. И если удовлетворяет условию, то следующая точка помещается в массив из двух, вытесняя первую. В общем то не важно, что они рандомные. Главное: как проанализировать кривую, имея в распоряжении начальные, конечные и контрольные точки кубических Безье. И не понятно, где ошибка в моей логике. В подавляющем числе случаев все работает, но иногда и нет. Почему?

Comment: @Leonid: тут ещё один нюанс - так как всё это параметрика и векторы, а используются кривые, то при увеличении масштаба, может быть так, что острые заломы сгладятся. И наоборот при уменьшении - то, что казалось плавным, станет острым.

Comment: Такое может быть, но для этого я и установил минимальные расстояния между контрольными точками, чтобы в масштабе "нашего зрения" не было кажущихся изломов (?). И меня беспокоит другой факт, почему при указании, скажем 80, 90, 120 градусов, за редким исключение процесс падает. Хотя при 90 градусах в обе стороны - вероятность 0.5 примерно для рандомной точки. Минимальные и максимальные расстояния отключаю при этом, они не влияют. Мне кажется где-то ошибка там спряталась. Саму работу функции `getAngle` я проверял отдельно, вроде, работает.

Comment: Хотя, может быть это позиционное явление. Например, последняя точка зажата в углу, предпоследняя под 45 градусов ближе к центру. Вот функция и не может найти нужную следующую точки и входит в бесконечный цикл. То есть, максимальный угол, который будет работать стабильно 44градуса только. Все остальные варианты загоняют алгоритм в ловушку. При 60 более и менее, а при 90 любой последний вектор, перпендикулярный и направленный на границу холста, и лежащий впритык к этой границе, будет вызывать бесконечный цикл поиска другой точки.

Comment: А какова исходная задача?

Comment: @MBo - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68512066/creating-random-svg-curves-in-javascript-while-avoiding-sharp-turns - изначальный вопрос. В ходе ответа возник новый вопрос, который я расписал.